# php, can exceptions be thrown 2 levels up?

Tags: php, exception, try-catch, throw

I know this is a weird on, but in my code, i have development mode errors, and production mode errors. This is the function i have:

```
private function error($message, $mysql_error = null){
    if( DEVELOPMENT_MODE ){
        $exp = new Exception();
        $trace = $exp -> getTrace();
        array_shift( $trace ); // removes this functions from trace
        $data["Error Mg"] = $message;
        $data["MySQL Er"] = ( is_null ( $mysql_error ) ) ? "" : $mysql_error;
        array_unshift($trace, $data );
        fkill( $trace );  // formats array and then dies
    }
    else{
        throw new Exception ( $data );
    }
}
```

I wrote this function in my database class, so that if an error happens, I don't have to provide the check if we're in development mode or not!

So I thought I could externalise the re-usable code. However, because I'm throwing an exception from this function, I'm basically just using a function, that will return a thrown error. Pretty useless in production mode.

I would have to do this every time i want to use it:

```
try{
    $this -> error( "Invalid Link After Connect.", mysql_error () );
} catch ( Exception $exp ){
    throw $exp;
}
```

RATHER THAN JUST

```
$this -> error( "Invalid Link After Connect.", mysql_error () );
```

so to avoid writing a try ... catch block for every error function I want to call... is there any way to throw the exception 2 levels up?

Comment: `I would have to do this every time i want to use it:` Why's that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An exception will automatically travel up the call chain until it reaches the highest level. If it's not caught there, program execution terminates due to an *uncaught exception*. The whole point of exceptions is to be able to have errors bubble up. You don't need to throw harder or do anything special to "throw it up 2 levels", that's what it does by definition.

Comment: OH! i didnt realise... i thought they had to be caught on every level. My bad

Comment: I have to admit I was tempted to answer `throw harder new Exception()`. ;)

Comment: but i do need to throw harder... it doesn't bubble.

Comment: I would like to say that if you are using namespaces, you may have to do `catch (\Exception $e) {` rather than `catch (Exception $e) {`

Answer (score 10):

Just omit the `try`/`catch` block. Exceptions automatically propagate up as far as they can until something catches them; you don't need to explicitly re-throw them at every level of the call stack.

This...

```
try{
    $this -> error( "Invalid Link After Connect.", mysql_error () );
} catch ( Exception $exp ){
    throw $exp;
}
```

is exactly equivalent to this:

```
$this -> error( "Invalid Link After Connect.", mysql_error () );
```

Comment: Almost exactly equivalent... `getLine` would return a different number. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Multiple catch Blocks 
use admin table which has field

```
Mode    Value 
0     Production
1     Debug
```

the first catch which matches the exception is executed

Example

```
 try {

    if (!$bDBConnection && $row['mode'] ==0 ) {
       throw new Produciton_DBException("Problem with Database");
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Debug_DBException("Problem with Database");
    }

 }
 catch(Produciton_DBException $e)
 {

  // display suitable error messages
 }
 catch(Debug_DBException $ex)
 {
   // Exception falls through until a match is found
 }
```